# SuperVisor for laravel queue fill the hard disk suddenly after installing

Tags: php, laravel-5, debian, supervisord, laravel-queue

Suddenly after installing supervisor for Laravel Queue I noticed that the hard disk become out of space.

after uninstalling the supervisor with

```
 apt-get purge supervisor
```

the space have been freed and the hard disk is back again to it's previous status.

I don't have any idea why this happened , please let me know if there's make something wrong with the default configuration

anyone have any idea why this happened , also is there any idea to run Queue for Larave without using supervisor ?

Thank you

Comment: Without `supervisor` you may have to manually start `artisan queue:work` command (`cron` may be of some help). Regarding disk usage, please provide more details. After the disk gets full, run `sudo du -h /` and see what's eating up all the storage.

Comment: yes I tried to use df -h and du -h the results appeared that the used space 100% with Available space 0% , I'm really not sure why that's happened with Supervisor and when I removed the supervisor with purge the used space back to 16%

Comment: By running `du -h /` you're supposed to find out which directory/directories are eating up large amount of space.

Comment: Actually it didn't show the specific directory

Comment: so I just removed the supervisor